# I can't figure out this mysqli class syntax

Tags: mysqli

First question here! I really can't figure out what kind of syntax this is, on the php official documentation. I'm talking about this, the representation of mysqli object:

```
__construct ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

What's with all these nested brackets? Where do they come from? I find this really confusing. I come from c++ but I haven't come across this kind of syntax before. Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that the arguments are optional and can be omitted.

They are nested, because one cannot leave out the first, but provide the third argument. All previous arguments up to the one, which should be passed over, must also be passed over.

Comment: Is it pseudocode? The thing with the brackets I mean. The assigning to initial values is familiar to me.

Comment: Yes, I guess one can call that pseudocode. It is a common way of specifying optional parameters. It is no valid PHP code though.